# I'm beginning with ASP.NET MVC and I'm getting this error: The name "View" does not exisit in this current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

Below I have attached my code. I'm simply trying to create a view for this page but I continue to get this error. I have already inherited this controller from controller base, yet I'm still getting this error. (Red squiggle line under View) Saying the name "View" does not exist in this current context. I have also created a View folder with a page called Index. Can someone help me with this?

```
namespace EmptyCore.Controller
{
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IBookRepository _bookRepository;

        public HomeController(IBookRepository bookRepository)
        {
            _bookRepository = bookRepository;
        }
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            //Book book =  _bookRepository.GetBook(1);
            //return new ObjectResult(book);

            return View();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you put your cursor over the red squiggle and press CTRL + . Did you receive some hint about adding using directives to your code?

Comment: 1) Extend `Controller` and not `ControllerBase`. 2) Make sure there is a folder `Home` inside `Views` folder and inside the `Home` folder there is a file called `index.cshtml`. That error is saying (2) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to make a view.

In your method Index you can right click "View();

Then you press Add View.

This is an easier way to make a view. Maybe that way it might work for you.
You don't have to make your own folders.